# Java - How to read multiple DataRow

Tags: java, resultset, executequery

I´m new to Java programming, and I am migrating an application from C # to Java EE. The problem is this, I run a query through a stored procedure that returns the paginated result, for example, imagine that I search for the name John in the database. The result of the query might return 10,000 John's, but I want to show only 25 John's. So my stored procedure returns two results: first the amount of John's found, and the second 25 John's selected (pagging).

In my C # code is as follows:

```
            // Execute a stored procedure.
            DataSet dataSet = banco.ExecuteDataSet(command);
            if (dataSet != null)
            {
                // Check if something was retorned.
                if (dataSet.Tables.Count == 2)
                {
                    // Get the total of records found by query.
                    _totRegistros = (int)dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];

                        // Lê os dados da segunda tabela, que é a que contém os
                        // registros e preenche a página com os registros de detalhe.
                        bool impar = true;
                        foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[1].Rows)
                        {
                            // Salva os dados no registro da classe.
                            ReadDataRow(row);

                            // Inclui os registros de detalhe no formulário.
                            listagem += PrintLinGrid(impar);
                            impar = !impar;
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    _temErro = true;
                    _msgUsuario = "Nenhum registro encontrado.";
                }

                // Libera área de memória alocada pelo DataSet.
                if (dataSet != null)
                {
                    dataSet.Dispose();
                    dataSet = null;
                }
            }
```

And here, my code in Java

```
    Connection con = Conexao.GetConnection();
    if (con != null) {
        // Create statement do execute stored procedure.
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            // Insert de statament with stored procedure.
            stmt = con.prepareCall("{call BackOffice_Usuario_QueryPaginada(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}",
                    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            // Add parameters to stored procedure.
            stmt.setString(1, "UsuarioId, UsuarioLojistaId, UsuarioStatusId, UsuarioTipoId,                    UsuarioNome, UsuarioCargo, UsuarioDepto, UsuarioCentroCusto, UsuarioLogin, UsuarioDataCadastro, UsuarioCriadoPorUsuarioId, UsuarioDataUltimoAcesso, UsuarioUltimaSessao, UsuarioAcessosAcumulados");                 
            stmt.setString(2, "Usuarios"); 
            stmt.setString(3, "1 = 1"); // Condition to teste
            stmt.setString(4, "UsuarioNome");
            stmt.setString(5, "ASC");
            stmt.setInt(6, 1);
            stmt.setInt(7, 25);

            // Execute stored procedure.
            ResultSet resultado = null;
            try {
                resultado = stmt.executeQuery();

                // This point is my problem, how can I do to translate
                //  _totRegistros = (int)dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]; and
                // foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[1].Rows) to java sintax?
                int x = 0;
                while(resultado.next()) {
                    x++;
                    System.out.println(x);

                    resultado.getRow();

                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                _temErro = true;
                _msgUsuario = e.getMessage();
            }
```